# Filtering data then iterating model using nest()

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I want to iterate over subgroups of a dataframe using purrr. But within each subgroup, I also want to trim some outliers, cutting at the 99th percentile of the independent variable (within that subgroup).

Oddly, when I try the following, I get slightly different results.

```
# generate a mock df:
set.seed(12345)
library(fabricatr)
library(tidyverse)

df <- fabricate(N = 1000,
            DV = rbinom(n = N, prob = 0.5, size = 1),
            X1 = rnorm(n = N),
            group = rep(1:2, 500))
```

Compare the output given in the first 2 rows of mods1 here:

```
mods1 <- df %>% 
nest(-group) %>%
mutate(filtered = map(data, ~ filter(., 
    (  (X1 < quantile(X1, 0.99))  )  
        ))) %>% 
mutate(
  test = map(filtered, ~ lm(DV ~ X1, data = .)),
  tidied = map(test, tidy)
) %>% 
unnest(tidied, .drop = TRUE)
```

...with the output in the 2 rows of mods_grp1, here:

```
newdf <- df %>% filter(group==1 & (X1 < quantile(X1, 0.99)) )
mods_grp1 <- tidy(lm(DV ~ X1, data = newdf))
```

I don't see why these are slightly different, when I expect them to be identical. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I think that in 1st approach after `nest(-group)` the `quantile` function will take into account the groups. In 2nd approach the `quantile` function inside `filter` will consider the whole dataset (i.e. no group splitting).

Comment: Can you show the output you are getting? I don't see a difference when I run it. What version of `dplyr` and `purrr` are you using?

Comment: Not sure how it's possible to get the same results. After creating your dataset run this `df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(filtered = map(data, ~ filter(., ((X1 < quantile(X1, 0.99))))));

df %>% filter(group==1 & (X1 < quantile(X1, 0.99))) %>% tbl_df();` and you'll see that the first model will use 495 rows, but the second one will use 492.

Comment: I agree it's your filtering step in your "check" that is the problem.  You'd need to filter to to just the group of interest prior to calculating the quantile for that group rather than the whole dataset: `newdf <- df %>% filter(group==1) %>% filter(X1 < quantile(X1, 0.99) )`

Comment: That was indeed the issue: I need to filter the data via 2 separate pipes, not in one, when making newdf